# ¿Cuál es la lógica para implementar un sistema de permisos en aplicaciones de escritorio?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, jpa

Vengo del mundo web y siempre lo hago a través de middledwares que yo mismo creo, o de los que que trae algún framework, pero en programación de desktop no me llega una lógica para restringir el acceso a cierta parte de un programa dependiendo de los permisos de usuario en la DB.

Estoy desarrollando en java: javaFX + JPA(EclipseLink) + Mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para permisos y controles de acceso te recomiendo altamente que uses spring-security. Que si ya lo has trabajado desde la parte web, pues no te será difícil implementarlo.
Es la mejor solución para seguridad tanto para aplicaciones web como para aplicaciones de escritorio con javafx.

Te paso algunos links para que te orientes:

stancalau.ro/javafx-and-spring/

dzone.com/articles/javafx-spring-day-1-%E2%80%93

Y no sólo eso, para tu capa de datos también puedes usar spring-data-jpa. revisa este excelente tutorial:

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/

Spring es muy flexible y su ecosistema nos permite implementarlo en diferentes tecnologías java (como javaFX) no sólo web.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu cliente es para Windows y quieres utilizar la autentificación del sistema operativo, yo te recomiendo Waffle: http://dblock.github.io/waffle/README.html